# How to clear a streaming RDD for every window?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import Row,SQLContext
import sys
import requests
import traceback

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("TwitterStreamApp")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint_TwitterApp")

dataStream = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9001)


def aggregate_tags_count(new_values, total_sum):
    return sum(new_values) + (total_sum or 0)


def get_sql_context_instance(spark_context):
    if ('sqlContextSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance'] = SQLContext(spark_context)
    return globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance']



def process_rdd(time, rdd):
    print("----------- %s -----------" % str(time))
    try:
        print(rdd.collect())
    except:
        print(traceback.print_exc())


def release_rdd(time, rdd):
    rdd.unpersist()

words = dataStream.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))

hashtags = words.map(lambda x: (x, 1))

tags_totals = hashtags.updateStateByKey(aggregate_tags_count)

tags_totals.foreachRDD(process_rdd)

dataStream.foreachRDD(release_rdd)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The codes implements a wordcount, and runs without error. But the question is, it is cumulative, whereas I hope the dataStream is cleared every window (5 seconds in my program).

For example, If I receive (a, 10) in the first window, (a, 20) in the second window, I hope it to output only (a, 20). However my code outputs the sum of (a, 10) and (a, 20), which is (a, 30)

Could anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use stateful transformations. Just `reduceByKey`:

```
from operator import add

tags_totals = (dataStream
    .flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(add))
```